# Projection with LINQ to MongoDb

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Imagine, we have the following query:

```
            var result = from record in GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable()
                 where record.ID == id
                 select new { createdById = record.createdBy.Id};
```

Method GetCollection() simple returns *MongoCollection*.

The result of the query is:

```
result.Single()
{ createdById = 67 }
    createdById: 67
```

Looks good? No.

If we profile the query we'll see:

```
{
"op" : "query",
"ns" : "dev-LocalQA.questions",
"query" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5538e0ad90a49720dcc5f8c1")
},
"ntoreturn" : 2,
"ntoskip" : 0,
"nscanned" : 1,
"nscannedObjects" : 1,
"idhack" : true,
"keyUpdates" : 0,
"numYield" : 0,
"lockStats" : {
    "timeLockedMicros" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(118),
        "w" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(4),
        "w" : NumberLong(3)
    }
},
"nreturned" : 1,
"responseLength" : 1369,
"millis" : 0,
"execStats" : {},
"ts" : ISODate("2015-04-24T09:20:15.882Z"),
"client" : "127.0.0.1",
"allUsers" : [],
"user" : ""
```

}

It means there is no projection here. The same profiling result I get when simply select full record.

Am I doing something wrong? Is projection implemented for *LINQ to MongoDB* at all? Looks like no.

Comment: [CSHARP-456](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-601): _" Apr 04 2015 10:55:41 PM GMT+0000
This has been implemented in the 2.0 driver and, when LINQ is rewritten, [CSHARP-601](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-601), it will be fully realized"_